# Sim808: Is My GPS Module Broken?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

Is my GPS module broken?

My GPS returns `$GPGGA,000250.262,,,,,210,,2,700,,*4C` as NMEA. Why there is no latitude longitude? the first value is the UTC time, but there are so many null values `,,,,,` Is my GPS module broken?

---

### Edited

My Sim808 model is [SIM808 Module GPRS SMS Development Board IPX SMA with GSM GPS Antenna](https://www.banggood.com/SIM808-Module-GSM-GPRS-GPS-SMS-Development-Board-IPX-SMA-with-Antenna-p-1062818.html)

[image]

What makes me think why is this broken is because the day before, the module keep giving me location for every second. The lock was almost instant. I use the module at the same place like before. It is weird because the module is so unstable, yesterday was fine but the next day it takes forever to lock location.

Comment: More likely it just hasn't got a lock on any satellites. What antenna do you have and where is it all situated?

Answer (score 1):

Many fields will empty until the unit can get a lock. $GPGSV messages will tell you how many satellites it currently sees, and how strong the transmissions are. The first lock can take several minutes, and it can be very difficult to get a lock indoors.